# Javac doesn't complain on not-catching exception (Runtime Exception)

Tags: java, exception, static

i have this in a class:

```
/* parses a Value out of a String */
public static int parseValue(final String text) throws NumberFormatException {

    String cleanedValue = text.replace("-", "").replace(",", ".");
    return Math.round(Float.parseFloat(cleanedValue) * 100);
}
```

For some reason javac doesn't complain that i don't catch the NumberFormatException in the calling code.

Can someone tell me why that is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Docs, [`NumberFormatException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)  is,

> Thrown to indicate that the
>   application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types,
>   but that the string does not have the
>   appropriate format.

Just look at the inheritance structure, NumberFormatException derives from [`RuntimeException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), which the compiler doesn't force to catch those exceptions. It's not recommended. You need to catch/declare only checked exceptions.

```
java.lang.Object  
   java.lang.Throwable  
      java.lang.Exception
          java.lang.RuntimeException
              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                  java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Now, a method ***is not required*** to declare in its throws clause any subclasses of RuntimeException that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught.

Answer (score 4):

`NumberFormatException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`.  The compiler does not require such exceptions to be declared or caught -- partly because lots of code could potentially throw such things as `NullPointerException`, so if we had to always declare or catch such things it would lead to lots of extraneous code.

Answer (score 4):

NumberFormatException is unchecked exception - which means it does not have to be caught. Read more here for example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I knew what unchecked exceptions, i just thought it was a checked one for some reason. Apparently i always surrounded it with try/catch blocks until now.